# 'undefined is not an object' error when using this.setState within a setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using a `setTimeout` function which runs on a loop alternating between a boolean state using `setState`. However when `this.setState` gets called in the function I receive the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating:
> 'this.state.percentages')

Below is a snippet of the code I am using - I would be very grateful to anyone who can point out the mistake I am making:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      percentages: false,
    };
  }      

loopPercentages() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.setState({ percentages: !this.state.percentages });
        loopPercentages();
    }, 10000);
}
    
componentDidMount() {
  this.loopPercentages();
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined the percentages property of state.

Comment: It's because the context of the function doesn't have the state. You can either use an arrow function within the timeout `() => {  this.setState({  ... })  }` or bind the context to the function {function () {  this.setState({  ... }) }.bind(this)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setState` callback function to get always the current state value:

```
loopPercentages() {
    setTimeout(() =>  { //--> this component scope
      this.setState((prev) => ({ percentages: !prev.percentages }));
      this.loopPercentages();
    }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from "react";

export class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      percentages: false
    };
  }

  loopPercentages = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ percentages: !this.state.percentages });
      this.loopPercentages();
    }, 10000);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loopPercentages();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello StackOverflow</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that although this fixes the error. This still produces a resource leak, since the timeout is never stopped when the component is unmounted. Use `this.timeoutID = setTimeout(...)`, then add `componentWillUnmount() { clearTimeout(this.timeoutID) }` to fix the leak.